# How to Assign Task to the User which is located in the Picklist?

Tags: trigger, opportunity, picklist, tasks, user

i have one requirement regarding Create task Automatically based on the Picklist value and that Picklist value Have some users..

- Opportunity.PICK__c = User1, User2, User3, User4 ..........
- When this Opportunity saved then Automatically Task has to be created with the Assignee of this User (Opportunity.PICK__c)..
- this is working with the Workflow rule but it's a Static and i want it be to working with Dynamically
- just because of in the future if User's are more than 100 then.....

Please Help me out....

Thanks a LOT !!

Comment: Nihar  -- How are you creating the picklist? hard coded as metadata? There is a max on # of entries in a picklist and when you enumerate users who come and go, it becomes a maintenance nightmare

Comment: Yes. but i've not created myself that Picklist with the Specific user, it's created byt client and they only want to use this kind of picklist...Thanks

Comment: so, it is a standard field picklist?  How will the values in the picklist be matched against actual User records? By which field in User? It will have to be an exact match - perfect spelling fidelity. If a user's name changes (typical example - marriage/divorce), then the picklist becomes out of sync with the User record)

Comment: Yes.i got your point and it's a custom picklist not an standard

Answer (score 0):

I coded and tested a apex trigger according to your use case. Hope its help.

```
    trigger TaskUpdate on Opportunity (After insert,After update) {

//loop through all new opportunities  saved
List<task> tl= new list<task>();
Task T = new Task();
List<User> ul=[Select Id,Name from User];
If(Trigger.IsInsert)
{

    for(Opportunity Op: Trigger.new)
    {

        T.Type = 'Email';
        T.Description = 'DEMO String';
        T.Priority= 'Low';
        T.Subject='demo subject';
        T.Status='Not Started';
        String userN = Op.PICK__c;
        for(integer i=0;i<ul.size();i++)
        {
            If(ul[i].Name == userN )
            {
                T.OwnerId = ul[i].Id;
            }
        }
        //    T.OwnerId = [Select Id from User where Name =:userN Limit 1].Id;
        T.WhatId = Op.Id; 
        tl.add(T);
    }
 insert tl;    
}
If(Trigger.IsUpdate)
{
    // Optional if you want to change assign task owner is picklist vlaue is change.
}
}
```

You can code what to do in update condition according to your use case.

Comment: this answer is not bulkified; you are doing soql inside of for loop

Comment: Agree with Cropdy...Rachit, can you please bulkified this trigger ?

Comment: OKAY Done. Hope it helps. Please do let me know @Nihar